Add a collaborator to a GitHub repository using email
I am trying to add a collaborator to a GitHub repository. I don't have their GitHub usernames and only their emails. is there a way to add them or send an invitation to their email?
I tried using this https://docs.github.com/en/rest/collaborators/invitations and putting an email but it would return a 404. I'm aware that it doesn't handle emails, but is there possibly another approach?
